# Making the terminal interface non closable

Tags: command-line, process

Let me explain in more details. What i want to do is when i click the close button on the terminal interface, the terminal should not close. It should remain open. How can i do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please explain why do you want such behavior. May be thing you're trying to accomplish is done already.

Comment: i want to create a login interface using the terminal besides the normal user login. What i want is that once the user does a normal login a terminal pops out asking for a user id and password and a correct login will allow access of internet in the system. The user cannot close the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Use ccsm (CompizConfig Settings Manager), enable "Window Rules" plugin (category Window Management), set Non-closable windows; you might need to restart compiz. It does not do exactly what you want - after setting that, you can't click the close button at all, there is no such button. I guess this is ok too.